# How can I find my most recently asked questions

Tags: support

I would like to see all the questions that I've asked.  Can't figure out how.  Can't find it in the FAQs.  I've looked although perhaps not thoroughly enough.

One might ask why, would I want to know?  That is also a good question.  One I will not answer here.

Thanks.  Hope there's a way.

Comment: Do you know you have a [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/368469/lenb)?  Clicking on your username/avatar will take you to it.

Comment: Plenty of good reasons to want to know. For example to find a reference to that *awesome* answer the hypothetical user posted a while ago :)

Comment: ...or upvote/accept some of the answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here they are:

**[User LenB: Newest Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368469/lenb?tab=questions&sort=newest)**

Comment: I see now that on my profile page, there is a tab for the questions I asked.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, more tricky!

Search for [`user:me is:q` sorted by newest](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3ame%20is%3aq). **Bonus**: displays also the beginning of question bodies, allows to search for something in your question, e.g. [`user:me is:q something`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3ame%20is%3aq%20something) :) Also don't forget you can change "me" to some user id.